# Java 7 to Java 8: Steps after getting default value from hashmap and then updating underlying map if not null?

Tags: java, java-8

I previously had a piece of old school code that looked like this prior to Java 8:

```
List<Person> databaseListOfPersons = ... //random list of Person object

Map<String, List<Person>> somePersonListLookup = new HashMap<>();
...
for (Person person: databaseListOfPersons) {
     List<Person> personList = somePersonListLookup.get(person.getId());

     if (personList == null) {
          personList = new ArrayList<>();
          somePersonListLookup.put(person.getId(), personList);
     }
     personList.add(person)
}
```

The `getId()` method for the `Person` class would just return `A, B, or C` as a simple string. This block of code pretty much checked if there was an existing `id` key available, and if not then create a new entry and then add that `person` to the list of persons that was  apart of the Map. If the `id` key was already and entry, then to just add that person to the list and it would update the value to the already existing key, further increasing the list of people with the same `id` key.

So I want to just update the code to Java 8 and keep up with times and I have the old code converted to this:

```
List<Person> personList = somePersonListLookup.computeIfAbsent(person.getId(), x -> new ArrayList<>());

personList.add(person);
```

My question is: ***is this proper?*** It feels weird having a list initialized and not being used and then having the `personList` add the object like previously.

Comment: Yes, that's proper.   But why rewrite old working code, just to go after whatever's new and shiny this week?

Comment: @iggy One might consider the one line version easier to maintain in the future than the four lines version. Debatable, but valid. (And yes, I agree that the code is proper.)

Comment: Yeah it just seemed easier to maintain and cooler/shinier haha

Comment: Consider moving to java 17. Java 16 is here for preparing.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen While Java 17 is a nice goal, I don’t recommend moving from Java 7 to 17 in one big step. Especially the road from java 8 to 11 sometimes entails some challenges that we prefer to take in smaller chunks.

Comment: @OleV.V. This is school code - so good for learning.

Comment: Well, @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I am unsure whether *old school code* means code that is old school or school code that is old. It seems we have interpreted it differently.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen why should the OP move to a Java version that has not been release yet? In what regard would that move change the answer?

Comment: @holger School code -> the revision is for learning.  Java 17 will be a version hanging around for quite a while so it is good to learn.  Java 16 is here for preparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is proper, it’s fine.

You may want to take it a step further and use a stream operation. Simple version:

```
    somePersonListLookup = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId));
```

As you can see, this assigns a new map to `somePersonListLookup` thus discarding any content that it may already have. If you need to preserve old content or just need to preserve the same map because other references to it may exist, stick to the code you have already written. As i said, it’s fine.

Comment: It’s worth noting that the Stream operation basically does the same as the OP’s approach under the hood, including calling `computeIfAbsent`. This underlines that the `computeIfAbsent` approach is proper.